# MHDDFS randomly breaks

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fuse

I am using [MHDDFS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/mhddfs.1.html) to pool a bunch of large disks together into a single filesystem that I can easily share across a network.

For some reason every now and then the virtual filesystem seems to fall apart and I get a "cannot access datastore: Transport endpoint is not connected" whenever I perform an `ls` command in the directory containing the virtual filesystem.

As a result the filesystem becomes unusable accross the network. I have clients accessing it via SAMBA (windows) and NFS.

I have seen many users complain about this online but all the suggested solutions are unacceptable to me. Most people suggest unmounting and remounting the filesystem. A machine restart also works. I don't want to do this because then I have to SSH into the box every time this happens.

I'd like to know *why* this happens. The MHDDFS logfile is useless since it simply stops at the last file access entry and does not say what went wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there any other relevant seeming logs in syslog or dmesg?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I will grok the logs asap and update my question with any relevant findings. I reread the MHDDFS manpage and saw that the default loglevel is not debug. So I will reenable it tonight to see if I can learn anything. Leaving logging on the standard loglevel gives me a <50GB (!!) logfile after 7 days though.

Comment: at least while you are having issues, turn on the debug log.  Make sure it is NOT stored inside the mhddfs mount.  Also, check health of all drives with smartctl - many mhddfs issues i have had were triggered by small issues in the underlying drives.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be [a bug in version 0.1.39 of mhddfs on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mhddfs/+bug/1429402). A workaround is to downgrade to 0.1.38 from Precise.

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted, but I will do this tonight. With my luck after enabling the debug logging MHDDFS have become rock solid with no crashes for almost a week!

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the bug and have a patch out. https://github.com/ram-nat/mhddfs/commit/26d0f119eaa7e3ffaaf330bf29672e13471cb091

Details: http://nramkumar.org/tech/blog/2015/09/23/mhddfs-crash-with-ubuntu-14-04/